# Route voyager posts index not defined

Tags: laravel-5

I just have installed voyager at laravel 5.4 and tables migrated but at the end it shows following error

```
Route [voyager.posts.index] not defined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re runing `php artisan voyager:install` will resolve the issue.

Comment: It did not fix it for me...

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned by @Muhammad Muazzam

1- Run `php artisan voyager:install`

However, only this didn't work for me, I needed to also

2- Clear php catch: `php artisan optimize:clear`

Comment: Both did not work for me. Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, check the code and see if your routes are properly defined